# Remote control with nodejs and cordova

Tags: node.js, cordova, lan

I want to create a sort of remote control from my smartphone to my pc. I've created a server in my pc written with nodejs (using expressjs) and listening in a port. I want to make an app for my smartphone with cordova but I don't know how the app can know automatically the ip address of the server running in pc in my local network.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge the best approach is to create a UDP server listening for broadcasts and send an UDP broadcast to the network segment from your APP. I have this working with Python. As long as your local router/access point is not blocking UDP broadcasts you should be fine.